# Exercise grouping - Should I group exercises targeting the same part of the body?

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique, exercise-frequency

I am doing groups of exercises in the same day. My usual pattern is to do one exercise each of Chest, Shoulders, Back, Bicep, and Tricep respectively.
After finishing I do another exercise for Chest, Shoulders, Back, Bi, and Tri respectively, and again for the 3rd time

I would like to know whether is it better to do it the way I am doing it, or to train each area through three different exercises one after the other, then move on to the next body part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you pose it there seems to be at least a big imbalance in your program.

If you train a large *group* of muscles like the back with the same volume as a small muscle like the biceps, it is unbalanced.

Also, I see no mention of training legs. Again, balance.

If you like to do a split routine I would recommend doing a three-way split: legs, back and front.

Comment: I'm still waiting for the day that a general understanding exists that muscles don't work in isolation. We should be training movement patterns not muscle groups.

Comment: Agreed. If your goal is hypertrophy though, isolation goes a long way.